# Open GL ES error: undefined reference to 'glDispatchCompute'

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0, opengl-es-3.1

I am using Open GL ES 3.1 in Android app with native C++ code. So I need to run a C++ lib with Android support.

I have used some Open GL ES functions and they worked well. But when I tried to use `glDispatchCompute`, a linker gave a following `error: undefined reference to 'glDispatchCompute'`.

Here is the call:

```
glDispatchCompute(10, 1, 1);
```

Here are my includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <jni.h>
#include <GLES3/gl31.h>
#include <GLES/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3ext.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Here are my options for clang:

```
-lGLESv3 -lGLESv2 -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL
```

Also I tried `-lGLESv3 -lEGL` with the same effect.

Comment: So far I realized that the function that do not work are device-specific, and Open GL ES contains only headers for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in not using proper java libraries and activities. In [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/gles3jni) there are 3 activities in Java. After adding them everything worked well.